# Count total item types and number in a column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, unique

Let's say I have a column with values like
types

```
CPU
CPU
CPU
VDU
VDU
```

I want to count the number of times an item like **CPU** is in that column.

My query

```sql
select COUNT( * ) as total from `table` where `types` like "%CPU%"
```

But here I know that there is an item named **cpu**. Can I write a query that gives me the number of times a value occurs. Like the query should return 
CPU:3
VDU:2......

Comment: Yes, you can group by types , please read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to P.Salmon's comment,  You can use `GroupBy` to achieve it, it seems to look like below

```
select COUNT(*) as total, `types`  
from `table` 
where `types` like "%_your_filter_condition_here_%"
group by `types`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got it to work

```sql
select COUNT(*) as total, `DeviceType`
from `inventory-core-table`  
group by `DeviceType`
```

Comment: my bad, i didnt see that I hadnt accepted it yet. Apologies